# Bootstrap for Confidence Intervals

Tags: r, statistics, replication, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

My problem is as follows:
Firstly, I have to create 1000 bootstrap samples of size 100 of a "theta hat". I have a random variable X which follows a scaled t_5-distribution. The following code creates 1000 bootstrap samples of theta hat:

```
library("metRology", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
 # Draw some data
data <- rt.scaled(100, df=5, mean=0, sd=2)

thetahatsq <- function(x){(3/500)*sum(x^2)}
sqrt(thetahatsq(data))

n <- 100

thetahat <- function(x){sqrt(thetahatsq(x))}
thetahat(data)

# Draw 1000 samples of size 100 from the fitted distribution, and compute the thetahat
tstar<-replicate(1000,thetahat(rt.scaled(n, df=5, mean=0, sd=thetahat(data)))) 
mean(tstar)

hist(tstar, breaks=20, col="lightgreen")
```

Now I want to compare the accuracy of coverage probabilities and the widths of 95% bootstrap conﬁdence intervals constructed using the percentile method. I want to repeat the code above 1000 times, and in each case, check if the true value of the parameter belongs to the corresponding bootstrap conﬁdence interval and calculate the length of each interval. Then average the resulting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the best way to bootstrap is to use base package `boot`. Functions `boot` and `boot.ci` are meant for what you want, and function `boot.ci` gives you options on the type of confidence intervals to compute, including `type = "perc"`.

See if the following answers your question.

```
set.seed(402)    # make the results reproducible
data <- rt.scaled(100, df=5, mean=0, sd=2)

stat <- function(data, index) thetahat(data[index])

hans <- function(data, statistic, R){
    b <- boot::boot(data, statistic, R = R)
    ci <- boot::boot.ci(b, type = "perc")
    lower <- ci$percent[4]
    upper <- ci$percent[5]
    belongs <- lower <= true_val && true_val <= upper
    data.frame(lower, upper, belongs)
}

true_val <- sqrt(thetahatsq(data))

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(1000), function(i) hans(data, statistic = stat, R = n)))
head(df)
#     lower    upper belongs
#1 1.614047 2.257732    TRUE
#2 1.592893 2.144660    TRUE
#3 1.669754 2.187214    TRUE
#4 1.625061 2.210883    TRUE
#5 1.628343 2.220374    TRUE
#6 1.633949 2.341693    TRUE

colMeans(df)
#   lower    upper  belongs 
#1.615311 2.227224 1.000000
```

**Explanation:**

- Function `stat` is a wrapper for your statistic of interest, to be used by `boot`.
- Function `hans` automates the call to `boot::boot` and `boot::boot.ci`.
- The calls to `hans` are made by `lapply`, a loop in disguise.
- The results are returned as a list of data.frames, so we need to call `do.call` in order to `rbind` them into `df`.
- The rest is standard `R` code.

Comment: Makes sense! Can this be changed to using the bootstrap t instead of the percentile method?

Comment: or do I need another package for that?

Comment: @HansChristensen You probably don't need another package, `boot` is rather complete. See the help pages `?boot` and `boot.ci` for (many) other methods.